# Как сделать пользовательский "Тег" боту в дискорд?

Tags: python, discord.py

Как-то в ютубе я увидел вот это:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqPnO.png
Вопрос - как это сделать?

Comment: Уверены, что это возможно?) Такой фичи не знал

Comment: Ну я понял что возвожно, вот полное видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8k19HcVC90Y
@ЧёткаяЧетырка

Comment: @Creeper22398 ответ есть в комментариях под самим видео — эти теги сделаны при помощи модификации BetterDiscord

Comment: @denisnumb Спасибо.